# effect of [0-9]* in a regular expression

Tags: sed, regular-expression

What is the function of **[0-9]*** in the following statement, which will write all lines that start with an even number, followed by a space, to the file even:

```
sed -n 's/^[0-9]*[02468] /&/w even' <file
```

Then, eliminating `[0-9]*` will have the same function/output. In other words, both statements are the same effect.

```
sed -n 's/^[02468] /&/w even' <file
```

Is `[0-9]*` useless here? I am really confused. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

The `[0-9]*` is not useless; it matches any number (0-9) that show up before the even number range (`[02468]`). This is to take into account multi-digit even numbers.

For e.g., if you didn't have `^[0-9]*` anchored to beginning of your pattern, it would not match:

```
92
910
308
20
```

The other pattern you mentioned (`/^[02468]/`) would only match anything that *begins* with an even digit.